# img is a self closing element: <img/> but contains nested content

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I got the below error When I try to run the pug view file.

Error: img is a self closing element:  but contains nested content.

```
html 
head 
    title #{name}
body 
    h1 Greetings from #{name}
        var img = 
    img (src="/mist1.jpg")
```

Comment: Fixing a typo hardly seems to warrant a self-answered question.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, It may help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the space intent between img tag and src attributes.

```
img (src="/mist1.jpg")
```

to

```
img(src="/mist1.jpg")
```